# Carolina Reaper leaves colour doesn't look correct

Tags: leaves, chili

I have a couple of Carolina Reapers I'm growing hydroponically but the big one's leaves look I think the wrong colour.. Is this the correct colour? If not what do I need to do to rectify it? I've included the smaller one for reference as it looks the correct colour... Note the big one has chillies on it:
[image: big plant]!

[image: Small plant]

Comment: Do you moved the plant recently? Do they have enough sun? Fertilizer/soil? For me, they are not so bad. The last one is too dark (for me)

Comment: Yeah but only after it turned that lime colour... It actually started turning that colour after it fruited. I've got some Magnesium and calcium which I'm gonna try on it.

Comment: What hydroponics method? Kind of looks like Kratky because i'm not seeing an air pump. Have you checked the usual suspects (pH, ppm)?

Comment: Also useful might be some climate information. Hardiness zone (if US), or other information might help. How hot is it? Is this the beginning or end of your growing season.

Comment: Yep I'm using the Kratky method.....i kept the plants in doors over winter... Put the seeds in I think around October time... Just sitting in the window pane, I have lights but for some reason the plants I tried with the lights all died. So what your seeing are the ones that sat on the window seal. I'm in the UK so only a week ago put them outside 20c...brought them back in as the day temp dropped to 12c night 7c...ph is 6 and ec is 3... I use rainwater as it has an ec of 0 then add the nutrient to ec 3 and pH it down to 6.